# variables passed by reference or by value (clarification)

Tags: javascript

This is my example code:

```
var foo = {a : 1};
var bar = foo;
console.log(bar.a);//1, as expected
foo.a = 2;
console.log(bar.a);//2, as expected, as objects are passed by reference
foo = {a : 10};
console.log(bar.a);//2, not expected, I expected 10
```

The last log doesn't give the expected result. 
Thinking that `foo = {a : value}` is the same as `foo.a = value` I expected that last result was 10.
What's wrong with my expectation? I think I am missing a big lesson here.

Comment: Objects are not passed by reference, they are passed by value. Eveything is passed by value in JS, but those values can point to the same object in memory.

Comment: This is incorrect. Values don't point anywhere. They are values. Only references point to something. And object aren't passed by value.

Comment: @elclanrs object that point to object in memory is _reference_ :-)

Comment: @marekful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: No, it is not the same idea. It is still passed by value, technically it is is called "pass by sharing", afaik.

Answer (score 1):

You set `foo` initially to one object:

```
var foo = {a : 1};
```

and later overwrite it with completely new object:

```
foo = {a : 10};
```

In this case `foo` and `bar` are no longer connected, because the reference is now broken.

Comment: I thought that to write a completely new object I had to write `var foo = ...`

Comment: No, `var` just defines a variable. You can define it and later assign new value to it, which will overwrite previous one. This is what you are doing in your code.

Comment: also if `var` missed, with assigning variable would defined in global scope

Answer (score 0):

When you reach this line of code:

```
foo = {a : 10};
```

foo is assigned a **new** variable; from this point on foo and bar are two different variables and for this reason the last line prints 2 as bar is still pointing to the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You are reassigning `foo` to a new object literal on the 2nd to last line.
`Bar` still points to the old object, thus you get 2 (which you modified on the 4th line).

If that explanation doesn't clear things up, it might be helpful to step back and try to understand variables, objects, and references on a higher level. [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/04_data.html)'s Data Structures chapter might be a good place to start.

edit: A point worth clarifying: it's important to understand you're not overriding anything, you just changed `foo`'s reference. They point at different things in memory now. That's why `bar` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo = {a : 1};  //foo refering to object {a : 1}
var bar = foo;      //bar refering to same object as foo
console.log(bar.a); //1, as expected
foo.a = 2;          //The object to which bar and foo are pointing gets changed
console.log(bar.a); //2, as expected, as objects are passed by reference
foo = {a : 10};     //foo starts pointing to the newly created object, whereas bar is still refering the old object(no change in bar) and the earlier object `{a : 1}` exists and poinyted to by bar
console.log(bar.a); //2, not expected, I expected 10 //hence this result
```

Answer (score 0):

first you have assigned foo to bar at that time the ref of foo is sent to bar.

now if you change the value bar.a then foo will be changed

```
foo = {
    a: 2
}

bar = foo
console.log(bar.a) //gives 2

bar.a = 30

console.log(foo.a) //gives 30
```

but when you over-write foo, the connection will  be lost and both act like 2 individual variables

so now

```
foo.a = 20
console.log(bar.a) //gives 30
console.log(foo.a) //gives 20
```